# How to redirect AFTER print dialogue closes? TCPDF/Javascript/PHP

Tags: javascript, php, tcpdf

I have an order form that calls TCPDF to turn it into a pdf for printing then automatically open the print dialogue.

How do I automatically redirect the browser when the print dialogue closes?

Comment: `window.print(); document.location='...';`?

Comment: `window.print()` does not block which i think they want